# plotly bar graph with variable number of bars

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart

I am building a analysis tool for performance balance changes and for this I have started a dashboard.Data is saved in a sql database for now and I am selecting the desired values by a dropdown.
My issue is with a bar chart - if the number of cars is consistent, all OK.
If I have a situation where the first data package is shorter (less data rows) and the others have 1-2 rows more, the plots are not correct any more.
Here is the data in question:

```
data = {'Hom number':[51,38,53,56,54,52,42,50,55,51,38,53,44,56,54,52,42,50,55,51,38,53,44,56,54,52,42,50,55,51,38,53,44,56,54,52,42,50,55],
       'make':['Aston Martin', 'Audi', 'BMW', 'Ferrari', 'Lamborghini', 'McLaren', 'Mercedes', 'Porsche', 'Porsche',
              'Aston Martin', 'Audi', 'BMW', 'Ferrari', 'Ferrari','Lamborghini', 'McLaren', 'Mercedes', 'Porsche', 'Porsche',
              'Aston Martin', 'Audi', 'BMW', 'Ferrari', 'Ferrari','Lamborghini', 'McLaren', 'Mercedes', 'Porsche', 'Porsche',
              'Aston Martin', 'Audi', 'BMW', 'Ferrari', 'Ferrari','Lamborghini', 'McLaren', 'Mercedes', 'Porsche', 'Porsche'],
       'model':['AMR GT3', 'R8LMS', 'M4 GT3', '296 GT3', 'Huracan GT3', '720GT3', 'AMG GT3', '911-991', '911-992',
               'AMR GT3', 'R8LMS', 'M4 GT3', '488 GT3', '296 GT3', 'Huracan GT3', '720GT3', 'AMG GT3', '911-991', '911-992',
               'AMR GT3', 'R8LMS', 'M4 GT3', '488 GT3', '296 GT3', 'Huracan GT3', '720GT3', 'AMG GT3', '911-991', '911-992',
               'AMR GT3', 'R8LMS', 'M4 GT3', '488 GT3', '296 GT3', 'Huracan GT3', '720GT3', 'AMG GT3', '911-991', '911-992'],
       'bop_date':['2023.04.13', '2023.04.13', '2023.04.13', '2023.04.13', '2023.04.13','2023.04.13', '2023.04.13', '2023.04.13', '2023.04.13',
                  '2023.04.19', '2023.04.19', '2023.04.19', '2023.04.19', '2023.04.19','2023.04.19', '2023.04.19', '2023.04.19', '2023.04.19', '2023.04.19',
                  '2023.04.22', '2023.04.22', '2023.04.22', '2023.04.22', '2023.04.22','2023.04.22', '2023.04.22', '2023.04.22', '2023.04.22', '2023.04.22',
                  '2023.04.23', '2023.04.23', '2023.04.23', '2023.04.23', '2023.04.23','2023.04.23', '2023.04.23', '2023.04.23', '2023.04.23', '2023.04.23'],
       'bop_ballast':[25,55,50,45,0,50,60,50,40,
                     25,55,50,45,45,60,50,60,50,40,
                     15,65,40,35,25,50,35,75,45,30,
                     15,65,50,35,20,50,45,75,45,25]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Here is one of the dataframes I want to plot:

```
fig_bal = px.bar(
    df,
    x='fia_gt3_homologation', 
    y='bop_ballast',
    # barmode='group', # does not help
    facet_row='bop_date', # goes right direction but splits into bop dcouments
    # category_orders={'bop'},
    template = "plotly_dark",
    text="bop_ballast",
)
fig_bal.update_traces(x=[x[0]+' '+x[1] for x in df[['make','model']].values])
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

If you follow allong the data, you will see that in the first data I have got, there is only 1 Ferrari and the next 3 data packages have 2 Ferraris each.
In the graph, I only see the first Ferrari, than, the bop weights are plotted for the second data package to the wrong car - I get a stacked graph for the first entry.

I have 2 questions:

- is there a way to plot this data so that I have all the cars as a x entry and no data where it is missing?
- is there a way to change the plot in order to have, for example all Audi's as a grouped bar chart with 4 bars representing the 4 bop variants?

Thank you!

Edit!
With the help of r-beginners, now I have the plot closer to what I want:
[image]

But I am still missing the entry for the second Ferrari.

This is how i would like to have it, just ignore the x-labels, as I quickly took the homologation numbers:
[image]

You can see, now I have all 10 cars.

Comment: Can you put the code for creating the plot in a code block? It is hard to analyze it currently.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the intent of your question, but if you want to group by model, I think it would be possible by setting the color to date. `fig_bal = px.bar(df,x='model',y='bop_ballast',color='bop_date',barmode='group',template = "plotly_dark",text="bop_ballast")`

Comment: Hey r-beginners, thank you for the hint, it looks that I have left this combination out in my code testing for the color coding.

Answer (score 1):

I have got a very simple and efficient answer on the plotly comunity forum.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['make_model'] = df['make'] + ' ' + df['model']


fig_bal = px.bar(df,x='make_model',y='bop_ballast',color='bop_date',barmode='group',template = "plotly_dark",text="bop_ballast")
```

This is actually solving all the problems I have had.
It appears that I have partly created the problem with an additional snippet of code by trying to update the x-labels.